# JQuery/GSAP - Moving multiple elements parallel to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

What I want to do is this: I want to generate boxes on the **Y** or **X** axis of the page (the bottom and left border) and make them move parallel to each other until they've gone off-screen, where I want to delete them.
This is what I've done so far:

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Dodicin/pen/NqOgBE)**.

```
function generate(){
  var $element = $("<div>", {class: "box"});
  //Generate random x and y coordinates
  var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - $element.width())).toFixed();
  var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - $element.height())).toFixed();
  //Place the box on the x or y axis
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  if(rand==0)
  {
    posx=0;
  }else{
    posy=0;
  }

  $element.css(
  {'position':'absolute',
  'right':posx+'px',
  'bottom':posy+'px'});
  $("body").append($element);

  //Move box diagonally, all the boxes paths are parallel
    TweenLite.to($element, 2, {top:0, right:0, ease:Power2.easeOut});

  //Delete boxes offscreen
  var $boxes=$(".box");
  /*$boxes.each(function(){
    if($(this).position().left >1300){
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });*/
}
```

My issues are: how do I exactly find the right point where to animate the box, in a way to move all the boxes parallel to each other?
And also, is there a way without using external plugins to find if an element has gone out of the bounds of the page?
Thanks for any answer!

EDIT:
Here's a drawing to explain myself better. Sorry for my terrible Paint skills!
[image]

Now all the boxes converge to the same `top:0` & `right:0` point, but I'd like to make them go parallel to each other, and so, each one of them should have a different top/right point to go. I'm guessing my issue would be to calculate it, but how do I do exactly? And also this meddles with the off-screen issue I take.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly the part where you say **move parallel to each other**? I am assuming this is working just fine. You are only having a difficultly to move them ***out*** of the screen bounds somewhere around the ***top right*** corner? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I added a drawing to explain myself better.

Comment: Sorry, just added it!

Comment: Does my answer help? Is that what you were looking for or did I just miss the point entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **[this](http://codepen.io/tah_med/full/mJzjdO/)** the kind of effect you are trying to create?

***JavaScript:***

```
function generate(){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var $element = $('<div>', {class: 'box'});
  var initX = parseInt(Math.random() * windowWidth) - (windowWidth * 0.5);
  var destX = parseInt(initX) + $(window).height();

  $('body').append($element);
  TweenLite.fromTo($element, 2, {x:initX, y:0}, {x:destX, y:-windowHeight, ease:Power2.easeOut, onComplete: onCompleteAnimation, onCompleteParams: [$element]});
}

function onCompleteAnimation($element) {
  $element.remove();
}
```

You will notice that I am not animating `top` and `left` (or `right`) properties with `position: absolute;` that you were previously doing. Instead, I am animating `x` and `y` which are essentially `translate(x, y)` values. This makes the animation look smooth: **[Link](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted to do!
Let me ask you something though: what does the `- (windowWidth * 0.5)` do, calculating the starting x position?

Comment: Since everything is moving in a diagonal path, it makes sense to subtract out a few pixels so that the boxes cover most of the visual space when they finally reach their destination values. This `- (windowWidth * 0.5)` part helps to keep the `destX` position just a bit towards the centre of screen. Try removing it completely and playing around with it to get an idea of what it does. Essentially, `parseInt(Math.random() * windowWidth)` for `initX` should be enough but ***subtracting*** a few pixels help.