# Reduce frames in TweenMax

Tags: javascript, gsap

This is the pen that I found: http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/Krfod.

```
TweenMax.to(document.getElementById('creature'), 5, {
  bezier: {
    type: 'cubic',
    values: [{ x: 100, y: 400 }, { x: 400, y: 100 }, { x: 500, y: 500 }, { x: 10, y: 400 }],
    autoRotate: ['x', 'y', 'rotation', 0, true]
  },
  ease: Power1.easeInOut
});
```

I don't know how to reduce the frame, I mean the only part I need is:

```
TweenMax.to(document.getElementById('creature'), 5, {
  bezier: {
    type: 'cubic',
    values: [{ x: 100, y: 400 }],
    autoRotate: ['x', 'y', 'rotation', 0, true]
  },
  ease: Power1.easeInOut
});
```

But when I delete additional frames, it doesn't work. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. With `cubic`, you'll have to provide values in the following format: anchor - 2 control points - anchor. Do you mean you only want the figure to go to `100:400` from `0:0` (its starting point)?

Comment: yes , actually i want to move the object from 0:0 to 100:400

Comment: Then correct the `values` accordingly: `values:[{x:0,y:0},{x:100, y:250}, {x:150, y:100}, {x:100, y:400}]`. First and last elements of the array are anchors (starting and ending points), elements in between - so-called control points (used to build a bezier curve), so you can adjust the path by changing them.

Comment: @sani: do you simply want to move an object from one position to another with its path being very _linear_ i.e. not going through multiple curve poitns?

Comment: then all you really need is a simple **[`.to()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/to)** call . Take a look at **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/7ocwh50r/)** fiddle as an example.

Comment: I have posted some simple **getting started** answers here on SO. Please take a look at them: **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209926/jquery-animations-sequence/32211160#32211160)**, **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225748/hangout-evernote-menu-effects-in-datatables/32244678#32244678)**, **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143458/greensock-tween-fading-in-different-items-and-different-times/32143817#32143817)** and **[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630114/jquery-gsap-moving-multiple-elements-parallel-to-each-other/31636493#31636493)**.

Comment: @sani: go through the links I shared which contain plenty of links to the original documentations to **GSAP** tools.

Comment: thanks, i'll check these

Comment: @sani: let me know if you have any questions after you have gone through the links. But I am pretty sure, you will have your basics covered with GSAP by then :) It is a great suite of tools.